# How can I disable back button when form loads in Edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page(an edit form) i would like to disable the back browser button when the page is loaded.
But i can't get it to work.

I tried something like this

```
   window.history.forward();
        function noBack()
        {
            window.history.forward();
        }
```

I just don't want the user to click the back button.
Any ideas please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.addEventListener('beforeunload'..` to notify the users that they will lose their work if they navigate away from the page. [Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Or, use the following solution as [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript/12381873#12381873):

```
(function (global) { 

    if(typeof (global) === "undefined") {
        throw new Error("window is undefined");
    }

    var _hash = "!";
    var noBackPlease = function () {
        global.location.href += "#";

        // making sure we have the fruit available for juice (^__^)
        global.setTimeout(function () {
            global.location.href += "!";
        }, 50);
    };

    global.onhashchange = function () {
        if (global.location.hash !== _hash) {
            global.location.hash = _hash;
        }
    };

    global.onload = function () {            
        noBackPlease();

        // disables backspace on page except on input fields and textarea..
        document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
            var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (e.which === 8 && (elm !== 'input' && elm  !== 'textarea')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            // stopping event bubbling up the DOM tree..
            e.stopPropagation();
        };          
    }

})(window);
```

[Working demo](http://output.jsbin.com/yaqaho#!) as created by the user from above post.

Comment: Thanks UBK. But the code does nothing.. I added it outside by jquery load and inside my jquery load but did nothing on IE and chrome.How is the being used in sharepoint

Comment: Did you check the demo? It uses setTimeout, so there is a delay before you can see it in action. I have seen it working for both Chrome and IE. Also, check the question thread where this solution was posted, you will find more useful information there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript/12381873#12381873

Comment: Thanks UBK. Does it need to go inside a jquery block or outside?

Comment: You can place it outside jQuery block. This code block is called with Window is loaded. Also, consider using the 'window.onbeforeunload' event to show a message to user in case they try to navigate away.

Comment: Thanks UBK. I had it inside the jquery block and it di the trick. But it doesnt work in Chrome.It works in IE and firefox though. Any ideas to make it work with chrome